# Custom Textbox Zoom - Return text to active datagridview cell?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have 2 Datagridview controls in same form. Each Datagrid has some columns where user will write long texts, so I designed form with RichTextBox that opens when user double-clicks these columns to enlarge text-entry. Code works, but I want to use same form for both Datagrids, so I should somehow return text to active datagridview cell. Here is my code (for Datagridview1):

TextZoomForm:

```
Public Class TextZoomForm

   Public OpenedForm1 As New Form1
   Private Sub RichTextBox1_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.DoubleClick

        OpenedForm1.DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = RichTextBox1.Text
        OpenedForm1.Label24.Focus()
        Me.Close()

   End Sub

   Private Sub TextZoom_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
               RichTextBox1.Text = OpenedForm1.DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value

   End Sub

End Class
```

DataGridView1_CellMouseDoubleClick in Form1:

```
  Private Sub DataGridView1_CellMouseDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellMouseDoubleClick

        If e.ColumnIndex = 1 Then

            Dim cp = Cursor.Position
            cp.Y += CInt(Cursor.Size.Height * (-0.5))
            cp.X += CInt(Cursor.Size.Width * 0.8)

            Dim f As New TextZoomForm()
            f.OpenedForm1 = Me
            f.Show()
            f.Location = New Point(cp)

        End If

    End Sub
```

Any ideas on how to return text to active datagridview cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your zoomed form  so that it doesn't know where its data comes from. Instead the control using it will pass the data.

```
Public Class TextZoomForm

    Public Property ZoomedText As String
        Get
            Return RichTextBox1.Text
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            RichTextBox1.Text = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Sub RichTextBox1_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.DoubleClick
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

End Class
```

To call the form change your code to the following:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellMouseDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellMouseDoubleClick

...

            Dim f As New TextZoomForm()
            f.ZoomedText = DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value
            f.ShowDialog()
            'Great breakpoint location.
            DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = f.ZoomedText
            Label24.Focus()
....

    End Sub
```

Using `ShowDialog` prevents the user from changing the current cell part way through your call.

If you need it modeless then you should:

- store the cell that the user has selected
- handle the `FormClosing` event.
- Test the `DialogResult` to make sure the user pressed ok
- write the data back to the stored cell.

Comment: And how exactly should I use your property for double click on ZoomText? I pasted your code, but It doesn't return anything to Datagridview cell.

Comment: I've updated by answer to show that you just close the form on double click. The data gets back to the cell in the line after `ShowDialog()`

Comment: yes now It works but still one problem. After inserting text into Datagrid I set focus on some other control to see entered text immidiately. I use Label24 for that, see my edited question (RichTextbox double_click). Now this doesn't work either....

Comment: I've edited the answer to transfer the focus. Just after ShowDialog is a great breakpoint spot to see what is happening and make sure it's what you need

Comment: Thanks, now everything is as It should be. Looks like I have to learn a lot about using properties in future. Big thanks !!

Comment: What you need to focus on is basic component structure. The golden rule is your reusable component (the zoom form) must not know anything about / have a reference to the object that is using it.

Comment: I'll try to remember this, I'll probably need this may times. What I did was just the opposite thing :)